# SVD of matrix with complex coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

This is a question from an old exam: Perform the svd decomposition of the following matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & i\\ i & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

What I have done: I planned to use the svd decomposition formula $A=U\Sigma V^\dagger$ so I calculate $$A ^\dagger=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -i\\ -i & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ where $A^\dagger$ is the complex-conjugated transpose of the the matrix A. Then I calculate $A^\dagger A$ and $A A^\dagger$ which both equals

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ with double eigenvalues of 2. Then I take $A A^\dagger-2I$ which gives me the zero matrix and a basis for that would be the standard basis. In other words U should be $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ Doing the same thing for the right singular vector give me the same thing $A^\dagger A-2I$ and the zero matrix again.

The problem: First, according to the solution, it should be the V that is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Second, U should be $$\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} & i/\sqrt{2}\\ i/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$$.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use \sqrt{2} for $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @Moo $A^\dagger$ is just the transpose of A, and then complex conjugated. This leads to the above $A^\dagger A$ above, and that matrix agrees with the first step of the solution from the exam

Comment: @Moo The solution doesn't really say anything beyond what I wrote. My professor shows that $A^\dagger A=A A^\dagger $, he concludes that the singular values are both square root of 2, and then say that we can choose the standard basis as the right singular vectors and what I wrote above in the question as the left singular vector. I did the svd decomposition in matlab and the result agree with the solution in the exam, so there is obviously something that I am missing

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong. SVD is not unique. In your case, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}A$ is unitary. Therefore $U(\sqrt{2}I)V^\ast$ is a SVD of $A$ as long as $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices such that $UV^\ast=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}A$. So, there are infinitely many choices: just pick a random unitary matrix $V$ and set $U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}AV$. In particular, you may take $(U,V^\ast)=(I,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}A)$ or $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}A,I)$.

Comment: thanks for the help. Just wondering, you say $U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}AV$. If I instead first chose U, would it be $V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}AU$ or $V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}UA$?

Comment: @user5744148 Neither. The SVD is $A=U(\sqrt{2}I)V^\ast$, i.e. $A=\sqrt{2}UV^\ast$. Therefore $A^\ast=\sqrt{2}VU^\ast$, i.e. $V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}A^\ast U$. You may also obtain this from $U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}AV$: since $Q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}A$ is unitary, $U=QV$ implies that $V=Q^\ast U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}A^\ast U$.

Comment: Great. Thanks! Just one other thing, here we use the V or U to create the other one, but in other examples I have done, each of the V and U can be done seperately. In other words you take $A^\dagger A$ and $AA^\dagger$, find the eigenvalues for each of them, and then find the vectors that span the eigenspace of those eigenvalues for each of the two matrices. If we try this method here, then we get the U and V to be the same, which is obviously not correct. Why can't that method be used here?

Comment: @user5744148 This doesn't sound right. $U$ and $V$ are never determined independently.

Comment: Okey, I looked it up again, and you were right. But here, it was lucky that two eigenvalues were the same (i.e. that we could write sqrt(2) times the identity matrix) What if the eigenvalues had been different, how would you have done then?